# Mútiplas chaves na sessão

Tags: laravel, session

Gostaria de salvar e recuperar uma sessão tipo matriz no Laravel tipo no PHP

***Exemplo***:

**no *PHP*:**

```
$_SESSION['dado']['dado1'] = $valor;
```

Recuperando

```
echo $_SESSION['dado']['dado1'];
```

No ***Laravel*** estou tentando assim:

```
$request->session()->put(
   [ ['dado']['dado1'] = $valor ]
)
```

Mas como eu recuperaria?

Assim:

```
echo $request->session()->get(['dado']['dado1'])
```

?

Comment: Não deu certo a solução @adventistaam?

Comment: Não sei porque, mas esta seção afeta outro sistema

Comment: Olha a sua pergunta é outra! se perguntou como criar a sessão. O problema de compartilha a mesma sessão é porque deve está rodando num servidor de teste! já visto que no serviço principal de hospedagem está configurado corretamente.

Comment: Mesmo em sistemas diferentes uma sessão afeta todos?

Comment: Seguinte a pergunta sua: "Gostaria de salvar e recuperar uma sessão tipo matriz no Laravel tipo no PHP" isso foi respondido. Ai você abriu outro questionamento é lá que você deve se preocupar com essa duvida é assim que funciona... !!! entendeu. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/301978/sess%C3%A3o-laravel-n%C3%A3o-armazena

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para criar um dado em `session` no [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) é o seguinte

```
$value['dado']['dado1'] = "1";
$request->session()->put('key',$value);
```

ou

```
$value['dado']['dado1'] = "1";
session('key', $value); // armazena a sessão
```

---

Para recuperar a sessão:

```
$dados = $request->session()->get('key');
```

ou

```
$dados = session('key')
```

Ou seja, o dado criado precisa ter um chave de identificação para que depois consiga recuperar qualquer informação.

<sub>***Referencia:*** [HTTP Session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session#using-the-session)</sub>